# Why am I wrong about the tangent bundle?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, definition, tangent-spaces, tangent-bundle

What is gained by insisting on the distinction between tangent spaces at different points and double-tagging them in the construction of the tangent bundle? What *specifically* am I missing by neglecting this distinction?

**Definition (tangent space and tangent bundle):** Let $M$ be a topological $n$-manifold. For each point $p\in M$, the *tangent space* at $p$ is $\Bbb R^n$. The *tangent bundle* on $M$ is the space $TM=M\times\Bbb R^n$.

---

**Motivation/Explanation:**

There are four things to keep in mind here

1. Thus spoke the gods: "the tangent space exists at every point and is defined completely independently of coordinates"
2. homeomorphism $\not\implies$ diffeomorphism
3. coordinate independent $\implies$ chart independent $\implies$ atlas independent $\implies$ smooth structure independent
4. Occam's razor

**Why "topological manifold" is sufficient**

In order for the definition of the tangent space at a point to be completely independent of the choice of coordinates, it must also be independent of the choice of smooth structure. While we *could* insist that the tangent space is only defined given a smooth structure, the only sensible way to do this without inducing coordinate-dependence is to tag the tangent space at each point with the entire set of admissible smooth structures - i.e. $T_pM=S\times\mathcal T_pM$, where $S$ is the set of all possible smooth structures on $M$ (considered as a topological manifold), and $\mathcal T_pM$ is the "standard" tangent space. This way, the absence of a smooth structure forces the nonexistence of the tangent space at every point.

However, if we do this, then we concede the necessary distinction between isomorphism and equality - since our ability to assert that $T_pM$ is distinct from $\mathcal T_pM$, is entirely contingent on their being non-equal, despite being isomorphic. For the sake of consistency, then, we ought to employ this convention *in general*.

That is, given two distinct constructions of the reals $\Bbb R_1\ne\Bbb R_2\cong\Bbb R_1$, the $S^2$ whose charts map to $\Bbb R_1$ is *not* the same as the $S^2$ whose charts map to $\Bbb R_2$. If we refuse to make this distinction, then equality becomes *subjective* - which is bad. Is this pedantic? Yes. Yes it is. But is also necessary for internal consistency.

Given that the distinctness of non-equal constructions of the same space (note the conventional use of the word "same") is not usually acknowledged, it seems reasonable that the tangent space at a point should not depend on the existence of a smooth structure. While we *could* still force dependence in far more elaborate ways, this would increase complexity without providing any real benefit.

So, the most straightforward way to define the tangent space is $T_pM:=V(p,M)\cong\Bbb R^{\dim M}$, where $V$ is some vector space whose definition depends *at most* on the point $p$ and the *topology* on $M$ (since, again, a change in smooth structure must yield the same tangent space to retain coordinate-independence). Being that this is a topological invariant, it naturally extends to arbitrary topological manifolds.

**Why distinct points have identical tangent spaces**

To force the distinctness of identical tangent spaces ("identical" according to the same convention by which $\Bbb R_1=\Bbb R_2$), we must again tag each of the tangent spaces with a point. That is, for $p\in M$, we have something like $T_pM=\{p\}\times V_p$. Why shouldn't we do this?

Well consider that the tangent space is not generally regarded as an affine space. If I were to say "the $T_pM=p+V$, where $V$ is the set of tangent vectors," most users of this site would disagree. But the affine space $p+V$ is distinguished from $V$ itself *only* by the point $p$. With this in mind, it becomes very difficult to justify the distinction between tangent spaces at distinct points without effectively resorting to "because I said so." And while, again, we *can* force this distinction by introducing caveats or additional structure, this once more only adds complexity without providing any real benefits.

Once more, the simplest solution is the best: $T_pM=\Bbb R^{\dim M}$.

**Why the tangent bundle is a product**

In keeping with the above, *if* we define the tangent bundle so that it can be constructed from tangent spaces, we cannot expect the tangent space to transfer any smooth structure to the tangent bundle - or rather, the smooth structure conferred to the tangent bundle will not necessarily result in $TM$ being a smooth manifold. In this case, however we define the tangent bundle, it will only be defined up to homeomorphism, not diffeomorphism (to do otherwise brings us into conflict with coordinate independence once more).

Now, I could be wrong here - I probably am - but it is my understanding that the *topology* on $TM$ is that of $M\times T_pM=M\times\Bbb R^{\dim M}$. Now, if there is additional smooth structure atop this, it will depend on the smooth structure on $M$, which, tracing our dependencies, makes the tangent-bundle coordinate dependent. This is not necessarily a deal-breaker - we still have the required coordinate independence of the tangent space - but it does mean that we cannot construct the tangent bundle directly from the tangent space at each point.

So, whether or not $T(S^2)=S^2\times\Bbb R^2$ at this point depends on whether or not the tangent bundle is a topological invariant in the same way that the tangent space is.

Comment: A topological manifold has no tangent spaces or tangent bundle. And certainly for most smooth manifolds your final equation is false. Start with $S^2$. Your first paragraph makes very little sense.

Comment: @TedShifrin Because? If we try to force the chart-independence of the tangent space at a point, we end up with something that is also independent of the choice of smooth structure, after which there's no reason to require a smooth structure at all.

Comment: You can define it, just it will not be the usual tangent bundle and what will it be good for? Will it help you to prove anything interesting?

Comment: The problem is that while each tangent space is isomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$, there's no canonical way to choose those isomorphisms. In particular, there's no way to do that "in a continuous way", so to speak. To see what I mean by this, maybe think about the sphere $S^2$ in $\mathbb R^3$, and how you would choose those isomorphisms from $\mathbb R^2$ to the tangent planes of $S^2$. I can guarantee that you won't be able to do that in a continuous way, and that's because the natural topology on $TS^2$ is not that of the product $S^2\times\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: @peabrainiac Right, the hairy ball theorem. But doesn't that only relate to the smooth structure? If the underlying topology is the same, can't we just pick a different atlas?

Comment: No. In fact, the Euler characteristic (which is the Euler class of the "tangent bundle" evaluated on the fundamental class of the manifold) is a purely topological invariant that can, for example, be computed from a triangulation of the manifold. For a trivial bundle, it is $0$. For the sphere, as has been long known, $\chi(S^2) = V-E+F = 2$. Of course, I still don't know what you intend to mean by $TM$.

Comment: @TedShifrin *I* don't know what I mean. I took the textbook definition of the tangent bundle (the disjoint union of tangent spaces), and the conventional coordinate independence of the tangent space and identity of isomorphic spaces and ran with it.

Comment: How would you define a smooth vector field using your definition of $TM$?

Comment: @William A smooth vector field on a smooth manifold $M$ with values in a vector space $V$ is a smooth function $X:M\to V$. The definition of a smooth vector is not coordinate-independent. Different smooth structures yield different sets of smooth vector fields.

Comment: @R.Burton As a side remark, you are mixing up *coordinate dependence* and *dependent of the smooth structure*. These are not the same thing.

Comment: @R.Burton Ok, now take $M$ to be a surface in $\mathbf{R}^3$. How do you define a smooth vector field on $M$ with the additional requirement that each vector is tangent to $M$?

Comment: @Didier The smooth structure is the equivalence class of smooth atlases diffeomorphic to some given atlas. An atlas is a collection of charts. Charts are coordinates. Suppose the non exitence of coordinates. What is a smooth structure?

Comment: @R.Burton What I said is that the words *coordinate dependent* are not used as an equivalent statement for *dependent on the smooth structure*. This is a worldwide convention. *Coordinate dependent* usually refers to a construction of something by the mean of a chart, that actually ends up not being well-defined on your manifold because it does not behaves well under a change of charts. For instance, it can be checked that the expression $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\det g}} \partial_i (g^{ij}\sqrt{\det g} \partial_j f)$ (with $g$ a metric) is coordinate-independent, while $\partial_i\partial_j f$ is not

Comment: @William That's just a smooth function $M\to\Bbb R^2$. The tangent space at each point *is* $\Bbb R^2$ (up to isomorphism, as always). If you mean to refer to the planes tangent to the embedding of $M$ at each point, these are not intrinsic to the manifold itself.

Comment: @Didier Most things do not behave well under change of charts. I'm confused, how do you define the smooth structure in a world without charts?

Comment: @R.Burton Read carefully. I never said that. You are assuming one's purpose, maybe by anticipation, but you are mistaken. As an analogy, on a quotient space, you can try to build a map by assigning values to representatives of the equivalence classes. This map will be well-defined if this construction actually turns out to be independent of the chosen representatives in the equivalence classes.

Comment: @Didier So "dependent on smooth structure" implies "coordinate dependence" (through the necessary existence of charts) but "coordinate dependence" does not imply "dependence on smooth structure" (since a chart can still exist without a complete atlas)?

Comment: @R.Burton Not at all, you're missing the point. This was a side remark, on the usual meaning of those words, but the conversation might turn out to be out of the scope of your question, so we should maybe cut it off

Answer (score 2):

I think you misunderstand. Nobody decreed the definition of the tangent bundle. Mathematicians wanted to study different types of spaces. Surfaces in $3$-space and their generalizations to higher dimensions. Matrix groups. Projective spaces. Etc.  Initially, everything was done using coordinates. But this became tiresome. By then it was already recognized that linear algebra was often a lot easier to work with using an abstract vector space instead of $\mathbb{R}^n$. So someone wondered if the was the same for velocity vectors or directional derivatives. It probably took some time but eventually the abstract definition of tangent vectors and the tangent bundle was forced on us. It’s the only thing that has all the properties we need for it to be useful. Nobody decreed it.

Comment: The question is not about the abstractness or concreteness of the tangent space - all spaces are identified with a single isomorphism class by convention (so that e.g. "$S^2$" isn't distinguished by the chosen model of the reals). The issue lies in the tangent space remaining defined if we do not suppose any charts on a manifold.

Comment: I chose to label it $\Bbb R^n$ for convenience, since that is the standard name for the space up to isomorphism.

Comment: As a set, the tangent bundle of a smooth manifold $M$ is the disjoint union of $T_pM$ for all $p\in M$. In that sense, $T*M=M\times\mathbb{R}^n$. You can if you wish view it this way. But the standard definition makes it far more useful. To view the tangent bundle as a Cartesian product is like viewing the reals as just an unordered uncountable set.